# Without releasing lock in Condition implementation in Python

Tags: python, garbage-collection, conditional-statements

I have a question about Condition.wait(). Here is the source code which I read at line 339 in threading.py:

```
    def wait(self, timeout=None):
    ...
    if not self._is_owned():
        raise RuntimeError("cannot wait on un-acquired lock")
    waiter = _allocate_lock()
    waiter.acquire()
    self.__waiters.append(waiter)
    saved_state = self._release_save()
    try:  
        if timeout is None:
            waiter.acquire()    # my question here
    ...
```

I found it only acquires the lock without calling release() on waiter later, so does it just let Python GC to destroy waiter? Is it good?﻿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for that specific case - `waiter.acquire()` being called when no `timeout` is specified - the `waiter` object will go out of scope as soon as `wait` exits; `waiter` gets removed from `self.__waiters` inside of the `notify` call that would be required for the call for `waiter.acquire()` to stop blocking, so there will be references to the object to keep it alive. Since there are no surviving references when `wait` completes, the whole object will get destroyed by the garbage collector, meaning there's no reason to release the lock explicitly.